# как быстро создать свойство property в python

Tags: python, ооп

Есть класс:

```py
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = ...
        self.__data_01 = ...
        ...
```

для каждого атрибута мне нужно сделать свойство getter, но атрибутов слишком много. Как быстро это сделать?

Comment: Через декоратор property

Comment: @eri это долго!

Comment: ну сделай цикл с ним

Comment: Если у вас в коде возникают нумерованные переменные/атрибуты, значит пора переходить на списки.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = ...
        self.__data_01 = ...
        ...
        for k in self.__dict__().keys():
            if k.startswith('__'):self.setattr('get'+ k, functools.partial(self.getattr, k))
```

Как то так. Если просто геттеров напихать...

Добавить декоратор property над partial чтоб получился property.

Пишу с мобильного, синтаксис не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

Если не имеет значение способ, то сделай словарь self.__data={} и обращайся по ключам. Ещё вариантом будет использование массива и обработки индексов.